# Uploading to Rackspace Cloud Files with paperclip and fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rackspace-cloud, fog, cloudfiles

Can't figure out how to do this? and couldn't find much help from anywhere else!

I have set up the paperclip and fog like this;

config/initializers/fog.rb

```
     connection = Fog::Storage.new({
       :provider           => 'Rackspace',
       :rackspace_username => '',
       :rackspace_api_key  => ''
     })
```

environment.rb;

```
    Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.update({
    :path             => ":attachment/:id/:timestamp_:style.:extension",
    :storage          => :fog,
    :fog_credentials  => {
      :provider           => 'Rackspace',
      :rackspace_username => '',
      :rackspace_api_key  => '',
      :persistent         => false
    },
    :fog_directory    => '',
    :fog_public       => true

})
```

I am using `file_field` to get an image and then posting it to my controller. This gets me something like this in;

```
"pic"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f90ac06a6c8 @original_filename="3245-1920x1200.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cloth[pic][image]\"; filename=\"3245-1920x1200.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130104-5386-103laem>>}
```

What I can't understand is that how do I go about actually saving this file to cloud files using something like this;

```
file = directory.files.create(
  :key    => 'resume.html',
  :body   => File.open("/path/to/my/resume.html"),
  :public => true
)
```

**EDIT**

Relevant Models;

```
class Cloth
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :pics

class Pic
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
    belongs_to :cloth

    has_mongoid_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
```

And in the controller this is how I am currently creating pic based on above params;

```
@cloth = Cloth.new
@cloth.pics.create!(params[:cloth][:pic])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's step back and look at the problem from different perspective. Can you see if the following script will upload an image to your container:

```
require 'fog'
service = Fog::Storage.new({
  :provider                 => 'Rackspace',
  :rackspace_username        => YOUR_USERNAME,
  :rackspace_api_key    => YOUR_API_KEY
  })

container = service.directories.new(:key => YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME)
container.files.create :key => 'my-pix.jpg', :body => File.open PATH_TO_FILE
```

Update the uppercase parameters with the appropriate variables and let me know what happens. Hopefully this will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: GOT IT! My container's region was 'Chicago', deleted that, made a new container at 'Dallas' and everything worked fine. Apparently: https://github.com/fog/fog/issues/1135 no one has fixed this yet. Phew, nearly drove me mad, this one. Thanks man!

Comment: Glad hear it! Just a tip, if you are using Cloud Servers with Cloud Files, you should use the same data center to reduce your costs.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer because led me to think about regions as it couldn't find the directory!

Comment: The latest version of Fog supports specifying the region of the Storage service. For more information please refer to https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/rackspace/docs/storage.md#create-service

Comment: **service.directories.get** it is very slow because it returns redundant details: bytes, count. How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

Paperclip and ActiveRecord should automatically handle the file upload for you. Here is a good quick start explaining the process:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start

If you are still having issues, can you provide me with the relevant controller and model code?

Comment: updated code above - and no active record and I'm using `'mongoid-paperclip'` gem

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions when you execute the controller code? Is it storing anything in Mongo?

Comment: No, exceptions. It is storing this in mongo: `[#<Pic _id: 50e6deb5e2280d530b00006e, _type: nil, created_at: 2013-01-04 13:52:53 UTC, updated_at: 2013-01-04 13:52:53 UTC, cloth_id: "50e6deb4e2280d530b00006d", image_file_name: "3245-1920x1200.jpg", image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 133675, image_updated_at: 2013-01-04 13:52:52 UTC>]` but not uploading to cloud files!

Comment: OK! now it is throwing this exception `Fog::Storage::Rackspace::NotFound in ClothController#create` and saving images to public/system but not uploading them

Comment: Ah! Looks like you are making some progress. It looks like the fog_directory setting should correspond to the container the files should be stored in. Do you have this value set to the name of the container you are using?

Comment: Yes! fog_directory, rackspace_api_key and rackspace_username are all correct, verified a thousand times